# Compile two Java files with JDB (Command Line Debugger)

Tags: java, debugging, command-line

Dear StackOverflow Community,

I need your help with the compilation of two Java files per JDB`s Command Line Debugger. Unfortunately, I'm not able to debug two Java files.

I know how to run, compile and set Breakpoints with just one Java-File. Everything is great and works fine.

However, I would like to compile two files.

For example one Java-File DoSomething with a simple Method:

```
public class DoSomething {

  int count = 0;
  public int getInt() {

    int i = 0;
    while( i < 10 ) {

        count++;
        i++;
    }
    return count;
  }
}
```

And the Main Class:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main( String[] args ) {

    DoSomething ds = new DoSomething();
    ds.getInt();
  }
}
```

If I start by the command line the Java compiler I can pass a breakpoint.

For example:

- jdb Main DoSomething
- Initializing jdb ...
- > stop in DoSomething.getInt
- Deferring breakpoint DoSomething.getInt.
- It will be set after the class is loaded.
- > run Main
- run  Main

And here is the output:

- Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
- Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
- VM Started: Error: Master class TestMain could not be found or loaded
- The application exited

What am I wrong or where is my error?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What Java version and platform is this? I just tried your example on JDK1.8_077 on Linux, and it worked fine.

Comment: I am using java version "1.8.0_102" on mac os el capitan version 10.11.6.

I just tried again, but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have access to a Mac system to try this on. It worked on Linux, with Sun/Oracle JDK 1.8._77, 64-bit. If this is a JDK bug, then it could easily be platform dependent. I guess what's needed is for somebody with a Mac to see if your result reproduces.

Comment: Dear Mr Boone,
first of all thank you so much for your support and your help.
I've just tested it on a Linux system and it has worked. I am a little bit confused and do not really understand this.

Once again many thanks!

Comment: Unless there's something freaky about your system, this kind of looks like a JDK bug. It would interesting to know whether running jdb in a remote mode, or using an IDE's debugger, showed the same problem.

Comment: I tried it according to the instructions of Mr. Herong remote and unfortunately got the same result. The page is here to find [http://herongyang.com/jtool/jdb_3.html].